# Google Sheets formula for date detection

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would I create a custom formula in Google Sheets which would do the following:

If Column A, B, & C contains a date then change column X to `YES`

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A:A)))*
                 (IFERROR(DATEVALUE(B:B)))*
                 (IFERROR(DATEVALUE(C:C))), "YES", ))
```

[image]